# It is possible to call a javascript function in android?

Tags: javascript, java, android, android-studio

I know that I can do functions in android and call they throught javascript, but I don't know if it is possible to call a javascript functions inside android (java).

For example, I have a little app in android that open a webview and inside the site I want to, **when user click on back button of device**, the **webview call a javascript function to go back to the last action** (of the site) and if it doesn't have an action it **closes** the app *instead* of `going to main activity`.

I know that I can use something like:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
   if (mWebView.canGoBack()) {
       mWebView.goBack();
   } else {
       finish();
   }
}
```

but it doesn't work in my case and I need to call a `js function`.

Someone can help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you can use

```
WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
webView.setWebChromeClient(new MyCustomChromeClient(this));
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.evaluateJavascript("globalJavascriptFunction();", null);
```

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView#evaluateJavascript(java.lang.String,%20android.webkit.ValueCallback%3Cjava.lang.String%3E)

The second argument is a callback.

---

[edit]

To get a value back from the javascript, you can do something like this:

```
webView.evaluateJavascript("globalJavascriptFunction();", new ValueCallback<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onReceiveValue(String result) { 
       // result is the return value of globalJavascriptFunction()
       // you'll have to do some testing inside here to figure out exactly how result gets sent back for your usecase
    }
});
```

Comment: Javascript function needs to be somewhere specific?

Comment: @CatarinaBatista usually `window.globalJavascriptFunction = function() { ... }`

Comment: but this code can be inside MainActivity.java file?

Comment: @CatarinaBatista `webView.evaluateJavascript("globalJavascriptFunction();", null);` assumes that, somewhere inside the html + javascript of the webview that you're rendering, the function `globalJavascriptFunction` is defined. You can call any globally accessible function from `webView.evaluateJavascript`

Comment: and if a function has a return how can I get the value? (I'm trying to do a test with other existing functions before creating a function to go back)

Comment: So as I said in the answer, the second argument to `evaluateJavascript` is a callback. The second argument is of type `ValueCallback<String>` as described [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/ValueCallback.html). You can create an instance of a class that implements the interface, or I believe you can define it inline if you want.

Comment: @CatarinaBatista I made an edit to my answer to show how you might get a result back from the javascript function back into your Android Java

Comment: I'm doing some tests, with returning String it works but It's possibe to get a boolean? I've tried but it says "... required 'java.lang.String´'"

Comment: If you know that every time you call that particular javascript function, it will return a boolean, then you can just check if `result` is equal to the string `"true"` or the string `"false"`. Alternatively, any function that you expect to get called from Android JAVA could be made to return JSON of a particular format, and you could parse the Json in the Java side. It depends on how flexible you need it to be.

Answer (score 2):

There might be something missing...
Go through the below code...

```
WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
webView.setWebChromeClient(new MyCustomChromeClient(this));
webView.setWebViewClient(new MyCustomWebViewClient(this));
webView.clearCache(true);
webView.clearHistory();
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);

...

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        switch (keyCode) {
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                if (mWebView.canGoBack()) {
                    mWebView.goBack();
                } else {
                    finish();
                }
                return true;
        }

    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: why onKeyDown? it is not supposed to be onBackPressed?

Comment: with onBackPressed() method, It will consider android cycle, while with onKeyDown() It will consider webView cycle.

Comment: It doesn't work, because the site that I'm accessing, doesn't have something with history or navegation

Comment: It works for me...checkout: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HqKJCU_u-Elg_enGqpzAMMI2FBaHAmed/view?usp=sharing If you still found this is not working please share some code of gradle and manifest for some more info...

Comment: but I've tried with google and it works, but I'm trying to do the same with another site created by my colleagues and I think that I need to call js functions to do that

Comment: may I have that site URL for implementing some demo from my side If you don't mind?

Comment: I really appreciate your help, but unfortunately I can't share it...

Comment: no problem, hope you will have your solution soon. :)

Comment: Sorry to bother you, if you understand good of android studio, can you take a look at my other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59686516/webview-doesnt-open-some-sites-in-recent-versions-of-android)?